# WCF Service - Asynch Operation or Queued Messaging

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service hosted as Windows Service with most of its methods currently defined as:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
```

But, now I need to send response back to the calling Web application for these service methods.

Now, because service methods are bit heavy (FYI, they are reporting methods that needs to do mail merge for a no. of records), I am thinking to either queue them or to process asynchronously, so essentially when the request is sent to the service it should save the request to database/queue, returning Request-Id to calling Web application.

- In the mean-time, WCF service can just process incompleted requests from the queue or database.
- Then either calling Web application can ping WCF service for status of request because it has Request-Id or
- WCF service can ping back to calling app when the process corresponding to a Request-Id is completed.

To achieve above, can anyone please guide what changes I need to make to my WCF service (which currently has all one way operation)?

Also, please guide me whether I need to go for Asynch operation or message queuing?

Thank you!

Comment: I personally would stick with "ping for status updates". Ootherwise your client gets a bit more bloated with creating an endpoint so the service can pass back messages.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, going Async is simple:
remove the OneWay on the OperationContract in question and regenerate your Service WITH Async methods. There's a reason why Silverlight forces you to use Async operations. They do force you to rethink your UI.